# Understanding XAP1167 port for zedboard

Tags: opencv, partitioning, face-recognition, xilinx

I tried to work with XAP1167 port for zedboard. It successfully worked for me on zedboard.
But I am not able to understand how the hardware implmentation is done! In the 'sw/sobel_cmd/src' folder we get a c program file where the software implementation of sobel filter is given. But I am not able to understand the implmentation method employed for HW implementation. Also there is no manual or enough documentation in the code to understand further in the code. I want to implement a partioned (or mixed - sw + hw) way of face recognition algorithm on zedboard.
Please help me at the earliest.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to design a sobel filter block in the EDK design tools.
Go to this blog it will solve your issue.
http://shakithweblog.blogspot.kr/2012/12/getting-sobel-filter-application.html